# Changing method name adds unwanted XML Block

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this is happening to my code.

I wrote a java program to add a block of XML to an existing XML file. To illustrate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bookList>
   <book>
     <author>Neil Strauss</author>
     <bookName>The Game</bookName>
   </book>
</bookList>
```

Now, I want to add a book into the bookList. So I create an Unmarshaller and call it like so:

BookMain.java:

```
    ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bookstore.class);

    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Bookstore bookstore2 = (Bookstore) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(
    "./bookstore.xml"));
    Book book3 = new Book();
    book3.setName("Test");
    book3.setAuthor("TestAuthor");

    bookstore2.getBooksList().add(book3);

    Marshaller map = context.createMarshaller();
    map.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    map.marshal(bookstore2, System.out);
```

Bookstore.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "bookList")

public class Bookstore {


    // XmlElement sets the name of the entities
    @XmlElement(name = "book")
    private ArrayList<Book> bookList;

    public void setBookList(ArrayList<Book> bookList) {
        this.bookList = bookList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Book> getBooksList() {
        return bookList;
    }
}
```

This works fine. It adds a book within the booklist no problem. But then I change the two methods, setBookList and getBookList to setBList and getBList and suddenly, the output looks like this:

```
<bookList>
    <book>
        <author>Neil Strauss</author>
        <bookName>The Game</bookName>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>TestAuthor</author>
        <bookName>Test</bookName>
    </book>
    <BList>
        <author>Neil Strauss</author>
        <bookName>The Game</bookName>
    </BList>
    <BList>
        <author>TestAuthor</author>
        <bookName>Test</bookName>
    </BList>
</bookList>
```

Why would changing a method name add these unwanted blocks of XML and how do I fix it so that I can change this method name without unwanted consequences??

**Edit** Here is the Book.java as requested

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
// If you want you can define the order in which the fields are written
// Optional
@XmlType(propOrder = { "author", "name" })
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private String author;

    // If you like the variable name, e.g. "name", you can easily change this
    // name for your XML-Output:
    @XmlElement(name = "bookName")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have edited my response and added it as you requested.

Comment: I can confirm the output. Interesting question!

Comment: This is by far one of the weirdest problems I have encountered but after fiddling around with it, I have figured out how to change the method name without causing it to go haywire.

the getBookList() and the setBooksList() **CANNOT** have the same name! For instance, getBList and setBList won't work but getBList and setBsList will. One letter difference and it works.

(Also, what is the etiquette on stackoverflow if I figured out the problem? I know there's a stigma against answering your own question...so what do I do?)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's supposed, that a **set** method should exist for Lists. My XJC generated JAXB classes only have `get`, `isSet` and `unset` methods for `List`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB defaults to @XmlAcessorType(XmlAcessType.PUBLIC).  This means that it will map all public accessors/fields plus annotated fields.  When the name of the field matched the accessor JAXB recognized they were related.  When you changed the name it did not.  To solve this problem you could annotate the accessors or use XmlAccesssType.FIELD.

Comment: So does this explain why adding `@XmlElement(name = "book")` right before getBookList() fixes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's the second run, so did you verify that your input file / stream wasn't a saved copy of your last output file / stream?  If not, then you probably added (like the code should) the two books to a list of books that already contains the two books.

Comment: If I run it a third time with the method names changed back, it looks correct, with two book blocks in the bookList and the two BList blocks are no where to be seen.

Comment: When you changed it the first time, was copy then change?  If so, you probably left the old copy in the same environment.

Comment: Also: even if it had been saved (which it didn't), why would the xml tag change from `book` to `BList`, as if it took on the method's name?

Comment: response to my first comment: I'm not sure how to check that. I simply told it to print to the screen using System.out. I clean the project before every run.

Answer (score 0):

At least the problem is independent from adding a Book to the bookList. I suppose the reason is in the in the same name of the `@XmlRootElement(name = "bookList")` and the member variable `private ArrayList<Book> bookList;`.

Take a look at your getter:

```
public ArrayList<Book> getBooksList() {return bookList;}
```

if you rename it to the *standard* method name `getBookList()` you immediately get an `IllegalAnnotationsException`. Well, this does not explain everything ...

Comment: Hi! So after further investigation, I think I have another theory. The `@XmlElement(name = "book")` in my BookStore.java method should be right above the getBooksList() method. When I move the annotation there, the names can be the same and I can run the code no issue.